# "Each piece of cloth" or "each piece of clothing"?

Tags: word-choice

What's the correct alternative? And why?

Example sentence:

> Junko inserted her arms inside the washing machine and picked up each
>   piece of **cloth/clothing**---her Doraemon T-shirt, Her Mickey Mouse
>   sweatshirt, Hello Kitty panties.

Comment: To those voting to close: consider the examples explicitly listed as a good fit for the word-choice tag (see its [tag info](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/word-choice/info)). Based on those examples, I'm not voting to close this question.

Comment: @Lawrence - What I've got from your comment is *"The examples on the "word-choice" tag are horribly out of date as none of them would meet our current standards for questions."* Where the question can easily be answered by looking up the two terms in a dictionary it is not currently welcome here. Where a dictionary gives superficially similar definitions but there is a suspicion that there is some nuance which the OP has missed, a properly researched question is welcome. I've had a go at improving the tag examples.

Comment: @Lawrence The close-vote reason is 'lack of evidence of reasonable research' not 'not fitting a certain tag specification'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Nevertheless, at the time I made my comment above, the examples in the tag info demonstrated a similar lack of research - and they *weren't* closed, for lack of research or otherwise. We keep pointing people to the site documentation, so we can hardly complain when posts follow the standards set by said documentation, especially when the documentation is tag info specific to the only tag for the question. AndyT's done the right thing, though - I like his set of replacement examples.

Comment: @AndyT is it possible to add 'Where the question can easily be answered by looking up the two (etc) terms in a dictionary it is not currently welcome here. Where a dictionary gives superficially similar definitions but there is a suspicion that there is some nuance which the OP has missed, a properly researched and referenced question is welcome.' to the info at the tag?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Good idea. Tag edit proposed, with slightly modified wording.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word "cloth" refers to the fabric that clothes are made of, whereas "clothing" means the actual garments that someone wears. Since this sentence lists wearable items (t-shirts, sweatshirts, etc.), the best word is "**clothing**".

> **Cloth:** woven or felted fabric made from wool, cotton, or a similar
>   fiber.
>
> **Clothing:** clothes (items worn to cover the body) collectively.

From ODO.

Comment: You have presented nothing to demonstrate that you're right. Why should anyone believe your answer? Please use dictionary references to back up your assertions.

Comment: Rather, please close-vote the question as not suitable for a website aimed at linguists.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What? I thought my question was `word-choice`.

Comment: @AndyT, my apologies. I edited the post to include quotes from a dictionary. I didn't before because I thought it was an obvious English-learner-type question, and would soon be taken down by mods anyway. The definitions are quite standard and unambiguous, and easily googled.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I close-voted too. But if someone's going to post an answer they may as well post a *decent* one (and learn how to write them against them finding a suitable question to answer).